# Using only some specific functions from lodash, but installing as a whole seems a huge chunk of depedencies

Tags: javascript, npm, underscore.js, lodash

In my project I have installed underscore.js but I noticed that I need the Lodash's `fill` function but installing lodash as well seems a big chunk of dependencies in my project, depedencies that offer similar functionality, thus making it a waste of time migrating from underscore to lodash, or using both libraries.

So how I can have only some specific functionalities from lodash whilst using the underscore.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each lodash function is a separate npm package as well. So you can use install only the specific packages you need via:

```
npm i --save lodash.^function_name^
```

Where `^function_name^` is the name of function you need.

Thus you can keep track of the specific lodash methods you need, in order to look on a latter time whether is worthing the time from migrating from underscore to lodash.